# fetch associative column value in select count(*) statement

Tags: php, mysql

Please i am trying to fetch the associative column value on a select count(*). here is my code.

```
$res = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from table where reg = '12' GROUP BY YEAR DESC LIMIT 7");
while($r4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){

            $totalscore = $r4['AVERAGE'];
            $len = $r4['total'];
}
```

`$len` returns my expected value, while the column AVERAGE is undefined i.e `$totalscore = $r4['AVERAGE'];` AVERAGE is a column on my database. Does it mean i cannot fetch associative column value if my sql statement is count(*)?? any ideas?

Comment: But you haven't selected a column called `AVERAGE`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not select the `average` column in your query
you can select more columns like so:

```
SELECT  
   COUNT(*) as total,
   `AVERAGE`
   FROM table 
   WHERE reg = '12' 
   GROUP BY YEAR DESC 
   LIMIT 7
```